# Test dynamic query but not actually execute it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT TOP(1) Field1,Field2,... FROM [ServerName].[DBName].[dbo].Table'
```

I want to test above query in such a way that it shouldn't return any result just to make sure every single object in query exists in specified `server+db`

I tried this

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(@Query);
    --My other stuff
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Skipping '
END CATCH
```

So, if query executes, I want to do `My other stuff`, if for example that `[ServerName].[DBName].[dbo].Table` doesn't exist it just prints `'Skipping'`. The problem with above query is that I don't want that `EXEC(@Query);` to get actually executed, I want to run something like that to make sure that that query would actually execute with no errors.

I think I figured out the solution
I'd use

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@CountNum INT OUTPUT', @CountNum OUTPUT;
```

And Wrap the @Query with above @CountNum

Comment: Are you trying to just check that the table exists in the destination server. If that is the case you still need to run a code to query that database.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to check whether table AND specified fields exist in that db. Field and table names will always change, I just don't want to go and check those thing for existence in sys.table

Comment: I would suggest stripping the columns and table name from the `@Query` and check for existence using dynamic SQL. That is the only we can check it

Comment: @EricKlaus But your "approach" will still execute the query and will still generate an error when a table or column is missing (or for any other of the many possible tsql errors). And now your approach will actually execute the query twice - once to determine if it "works" and then again in its actual form. Sounds like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Nope, it will execute only once, if there is an error it will go to Catch block and do nothing, if there is not error, that will store output in @CountNum and not display it and go further to "My other stuff". Where do you see a problem there? This way I can validate existence of fields and table name. I see where you going, you say it will "still execute the query", yes it will, but my problem was I don't want any output of that query displayed, and using OUTPUT resolves that issue

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `where` clause to your dynamic query so that it never returns any result rows. That way the query will be validated on existing tables and fields, but will never return any rows.

**Attempt 1**

```
select Id, Value
from MyTable
where 1 = 0;
```

> Error: Invalid object name 'MyTable'.

**Data model update**

```
create table MyTable
(
  Id int
);
```

**Attempt 2**

```
select Id, Value
from MyTable
where 1 = 0;
```

> Error: Invalid column name 'Value'.

**Data model update**

```
alter table MyTable add Value nvarchar(10);

insert into MyTable (Id, Value) values (100, 'ABC');
```

**Attempt 3**

```
select Id, Value
from MyTable
where 1 = 0;
```

> No error and no data rows are returned.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b57d3e44b13bca57bc0430a1e2ea4cd)

Comment: But it returns table structure at least, I want to put that inside a stored procedure, and stored procedure would return a lot of unnecessary table structures

Comment: I expect the "overhead" of returning the query result column headers to be minimal. No solution will return 0 bytes, otherwise there is no way to tell if the query was (in)correct.